# how to define the top dir in automake system?

Tags: linux, make, c, c++

I usually use a typical steps to generate the makefile, and firstly I use the "build.sh init" to generate the configure file, and then I use "configure" to generate the makefile with makefile.am file. Now I want to estiminate the "../../" in some include file like include "../../dirA/dirB/C.h", just write it as include "dirA/dirB/C.h", so the settings of configure.ac or makefile.am must be modified. Who can help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note, is that the configure system has two top_dir's. A top directory for where the source code resides, and a top directory for where the code gets built. Often these two directories are the same. But there are situations where the source code resides say on a read-only file system, so you need to build the software somewhere else. Below I am going to use the the top build directory, again noting that this may be the same as the top source directory.

autoconf already defines a couple of variables for the top build directory. One of them is called "abs_top_builddir".

Let's say the include file you want to use  "abs_top_builddir" is called `x.h`. You would create a file called `x.h.in` The way you refer to this variable in that file is to surround it with '@'.  So you might have:

```
#include "@abs_top_builddir@/A/dirB/C.h"
```

The other thing you need to do is tell the *configure* script to create header file `x.h` from `x.h.in`. You do this by adding

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([x.h])
AC_OUTPUT
```

to the end of *configure.ac*. You only need one `AC_OUTPUT` so if that line is already there, then you don't need to add it again. Now run `autoconf` to create the configure script and when you run `configure` you should see

```
configure: creating x.h
```

Check `x.h` and make sure the include line is what you expect.

---

And having written all of the above, I should also point out this this is what is not what is usually done. Instead, on in `CFLAGS` or some similarly named variable, you just include the directory. For example a Makefile.am might have:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)
```

Here I am switching to *srcdir* because I don't have to create the header like I did before. And you probably won't have to add additional lines to *configure.ac* because those lines will probably already be there.